# Replace text content of XML element in Python

Tags: python, xml

I think I'm missing something basic.  I'd like to access the text of an XML element and replace it.  For example, if I have this:
`<name>Fred</name>`  I'd like to be able to change `Fred` to `John`

I've read a lot of sites about ElementTree and BeautifulSoup but I'm still stuck.  Could someone provide a very simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

1. use BeautifulSoup's `soup.find()` method to find the HTML tag:

   ```
   >>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   >>> BeautifulSoup('<html><body><name>Fred</name><html><body>')
   >>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><body><name>Fred</name><html><body>')
   >>> name = soup.find('name')
   >>> name
   <name>Fred</name>
   >>>
   ```
2. use `tag.string = newstring` to replace the string of it:

   ```
   >>> name.string = 'John'
   >>> name
   <name>John</name>
   >>> soup
   <html><body><name>John</name><html><body></body></html></body></html>
   >>>
   ```

Then we done, check [the document](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-string) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

A python2.7 version of beautiful soup

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup("<name>Fred</name>")
soup.find("name").string="John"
print(soup)
```

output

```
<name>John</name>
```

Alternative using regex

```
import re
htmltext="<name>John</name>"
new_htmltext=re.sub("(<name>).*(</name>)","\\1Fred\\2",htmltext)
print(new_htmltext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just parse it as text?  The format of the data doesn't always necessitate the use of a special library for working with it.

```
>>> a = 'stuff<name>Fred</name>otherstuff'
>>> a.replace('<name>Fred</name>', '<name>John</name>')
'stuff<name>John</name>otherstuff'
```